# click home button in fragment page to disappear action bar activity title

Tags: android, android-fragments

- I am facing weird issue.I am using `PageActivity` inside three
  fragments swipes one after another and so on.
- My problem is,when I am in `FragmentA` page,on click the `home`
  button ,again come back to the application, my action bar title name is
  `Chapter`,which I was added the action bar title name in `PageActivity` and
  after 2 seconds the fragment title was loading with the help of
  query.
- My only problem is,on home button click in fragment page instead of
  activity title name,Fragment page title name have to be shown
  directly after enter the application.

Below I am posted the code related to this:

**PageActivity.java:**

```
public class PageActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 static TextView mTitleTextView;
.......
.......
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ActionBar(Constants.Titlebarcolor);
........
........
}

public void ActionBar(String color) {
        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textviewHeading);
  mTitleTextView.setText("Chapter");

}
```

**FragmentPageA.java:**

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
....
....
  }

 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
....
....
  }

 @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {

 //get action bar title for every fragment page   
   PageActivity.mTitleTextView.setText(DatabaseQueryHelper.getInstance().getPagename(getArguments().getInt(Constants.PAGEID)));
......
......
}
```

Anyone can give me any suggestion regarding to this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved this `ActionBar(Constants.Titlebarcolor);` line inside `onResume()` method to **onCrate()** method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar(Constants.Titlebarcolor);
}
```

So that When I entering into the activity,the action bar activity title will not resume.